# Is there a method in Python to print nested attribute use?

Tags: python

For example, for running the following code

```
host = Host()
host.a.b.c
```

The result would be

```
"You are trying to access a.b.c"
```

So far, I tried `__getattr__` but seems it would only print a and not .b.c for obvious reasons since it first tries to access a, then b, and finally c.

Comment: You are only accessing the `a` attribute of `host`. You are then accessing the `b` attribute of the `a` attribute of `host`.

Comment: Right :) Is there a sophisticated way to aggregate it somehow to eventually print "You have accessed a.b.c"?

Comment: You can't return that string. You could print it. Do you mind printing "You have accessed a" and "You have accessed a.b" along the way?

Comment: I do, because it stops me from implementing sort of lazy loading with Python and Mongo. That's the goal eventually. When  someone access host.a -> I can easily load a from DB. When someone access host.a.b.c, I can't seem to specifically load a.b.c and not the whole data of a

Comment: But you can just never load anything at all until you specifically ask for it to load. For example, in my answer, you could replace the `__str__` method with something like `.load()` or `.execute()`, etc.

Comment: Yes, but I imagined a different user experience where users have an interactive shell and they can do whatever they want so whenever an attribute is being accessed, in whatever that context would be (print, for loop, ...) the data will be loaded. Anyway, really appreciate your time and effort. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Look at how existing libraries solve this, e.g. SQL ORMs (such as Django's ORM, SQLAlchemy, ...)

Comment: Certainly the "for loop" context can be covered easy enough by implementing the `__iter__()` method (and perhaps `__reversed__()` if iterating backwards makes sense).

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly what you want to do, but it's part of the way there, maybe it helps you:

```
class Host:
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.path = path

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if self.path:
            return Host(self.path + "." + attr
        return Host(attr)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"You have accessed {self.path}"
```

Usage:

```
>>> host = Host()
>>> print(host.a.b.c)
You have accessed a.b.c
```

Comment: That's good, thank you. Wish there was a way to do that without using "print" :)

Comment: You can implement a whole bunch of dunder methods (with double underscores), so it's not just print but also for loop and addition and if statements and all sorts of others; there's a lot of them (see [3.3. Special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) in the manual). That would let you cover a great range of use cases.